# How to create a bar chart from Nginx access.log file with Grafana?

Tags: bar-chart, grafana, grafana-loki

My Nginx's `access.log` is read with Promtail and saved with Loki. Now I want to build a dashboard with a panel, which shows the number of reponses with code 400 (Bad Request) per calendar day.

I can parse the log lines with [`pattern`](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/logql/log_queries/#pattern) and filter the lines with a [label filter expression](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/logql/log_queries/#label-filter-expression). I also can apply [Log range aggregations](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/logql/metric_queries/#log-range-aggregations). But I can't configure my Dashboard to show bars for a calendar day.

**Loki query**

```
sum(count_over_time({job="nginx", filename="/var/log/nginx/access.log"} | pattern `<ip> - - <_> "<method> <uri> <_>" <status> <size> <_> "<agent>" <_>` | status = `400` [$__interval]))
```

**Query options**

I changed *Min interval* to `1d` to get bars for 24 hours.

[image: Query options]

**Panel**

The time label is not starting at 00:00 and the bars are not related to time labels. The days with 0 responses with code 400 are also not shown.

[image]

**Reasearch**

- I tried to use `now/d` instead of `now` (see [Time units and relative ranges](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/dashboards/use-dashboards/#time-units-and-relative-ranges)), but the result was the same.
- It looks like the panel is showing time label in UTC instead of my local timezone (UTC+2). But in the time picker, the local timezone (UTC+2) is correctly set.
- It looks like Grafana needs timestamps in UTC:

  - [Graph time x axis + 2 hours](https://community.grafana.com/t/graph-time-x-axis-2-hours/27977)
  - [Timeseries graph not showing point with correct X axis time value](https://community.grafana.com/t/timeseries-graph-not-showing-point-with-correct-x-axis-time-value/78723)

  But Loki already stores timestamp in UTC.

**Question**

How to show bars for a calendar day starting at 00:00?

Comment: Have you considered using `now/d` as time range for your dashboard?

Comment: @markalex I didn't know it. Now I tried it, but the result is the same.

Comment: Ohh, yes. Your research is almost right. Loki operated in UTC, and aligns interval resolution to round values (in this case 00:00), but later Grafana while visualizing data applies time shift for user's timezone.

Comment: @markalex I will look into Loki configuration, but I doubt that I configured Loki with local timestamps. I guess the default is UTC, so it shouldn't a problem.

Comment: I doubt that, it most likely not trivial (or might be impossible). It most likely UTC, and Grafana expects it to be UTC. It's just that Grafana while visualizing converts 00:00 UTC into 02:00 UTC+2. It is expected behavior.